# Why put an absolute value in the integral of the square?

Tags: integration, wavelets

The [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet#Mother_wavelet) article on Wavelets contains this:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi (t)\, dt = 0$ is the condition for zero mean, and

$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\psi (t)|^2\, dt = 1$ is the condition for square norm one.

Why put an absolute value in the second equation, given that squaring makes the sign positive anyway?

EDIT: $\psi$ is in $L_1(\mathbb{R})\cap L_2(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: Because $\psi$ is complex.

Comment: But doesn't it say that $\psi$ is in $L_2(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: thing in terms of PROBABILITY ... a probability distribution must be always POSITIVE and also the probability of finding the even in -oo and oo must be always 1

Comment: It certainly does not hurt to put the absolute value.

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt: you are right. Probably an abuse or wrong copy/paste, or "just in case" :)

Comment: it is wikipedia. There is not the kind of referee and copy edit scrutiny that math books get; even the best books generally have a few errors, certainly when it is a single symbol that is iffy.

Comment: $L_2(\mathbb R)$ usually denotes (equivalence classes of) square integrable maps $\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$. Or at least it has in my experience.

Comment: @Xeny Ah ok, that would make more sense. Thanks!